# How can i replace © and ’ these special charechers in java?

Tags: java, character-encoding, special-characters

I have to replace some special characters like ’ and  © Because while i am storing the text(which contains these special characters) into my database these are appearing as \xC2\xA9..(invalid characters.)can any one tell me how to store them into database as they are look like or how to replace them(it is urgent).
                                                   thanks&regards

Comment: Why did you tag this [html]?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your entire stack (Database, JVM, Container, Application, etc.) is using the same character set (preferably UTF-8). Changes are good something, somewhere is not. This will cause encoding errors like the ones you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String str = "text@";
String new_str = str.replace("@","");
```

Comment: oops! it is not working for me.And i want to replace © not @.

Comment: Hiya there, while this may well answer the question, please be aware that other users might not be as knowledgeable as you. Why don't you add a little explanation as to why this code works? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to URL Encode such strings before saving the string to the database. When you retrieve them from the database, you can URL Decode them before using them further (or displaying on UI, depending on your requirement). Even though this is not a case of URLs, but it will replace the special characters with more compatible characters.

URL encoding would replace these characters, for example © will be replaced with %40, ' (single quote) will be replaced with %27. For details on URL encoding, refer to this [URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

For URL encoding you can use the [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class and to URL decode you can use the [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) class.

Comment: Thanq Kshitij..and second one is not ' (single quote) it is ’ (ex:QlikTech’s)you can find this character in ex: string.

Comment: I see. Very difficult to differentiate, looks nearly same :). In that case, its encoding character will be %92. But the main thing is that you got the approach and it should work for your case. And also, as @mikkel mentioned, you may want to check the character set configured; this way you may not even need to encode.

Comment: ya! i have checked also what @mikkel said and i came to know my language java(UTF-16/UTF-8) and my database Hbase(UTF-8) uses encodings,but still some characters are appearing invalid in my db.

Comment: Well, in that case, try encoding them.

Comment: hi Kshitij, while i am using UTF-8 encoding still some characters are appearing like a "black rectangle inside with a question mark". How to display them properly?